# Can not use Jquery to select fullcalendar events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, fullcalendar

In my project, I'm using Fullcalendar.
All events have the "test" classname.

So, I tried something like this :

```
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("test"));
```

It sends me back a HTMLCollection with 10 elements in it.

So I tried to do the same with Jquery

```
$('.test').each(function(){
    console.log(this);
});
```

But it returns absolutely nothing.

When in doubt, I tried:

```
console.log($('.test'));
```

But I've just:

```
jQuery.fn.init [prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1)]
length: 0
prevObject: jQuery.fn.init [document]
__proto__: Object(0)
```

I don't understand why this happens

Comment: Why not retrieve the events and select them via the methods which FullCalendar exposes? Circumventing the library by accessing the DOM directly will most likely cause more problems than it solves.

Comment: Probably the FullCalendar is not initialized yet. Try using the famous `$(document).ready()`

Comment: Rory McCrossan : In fact I aim to create checkboxes, which would allow me to show / hide events when I activate them.

Roy : I tried but it's the same thing :(

Comment: If you used `getElementsByClassName("test")` and `$(".test")` in the exact same context, you'd get the results you expect. jQuery is not broken. You really have not posted enough code to illustrate the problem.

Comment: As to your current code, there's not enough evidence for your assertion that the jQuery loop would somehow fail. As Pointy says, if you run it against the same set of elements you should get the same result. To prove your point you'd need to show us a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because it looks unlikely/impossible the way you've described it. As for what `console.log($('.test'));` logs, it logs a jQuery object, exactly as you'd expect it to. Depending on your browser's DevTools capabilities you might be able to drill down into it a bit.

Comment: Okay guys, I tried to reproduce the problem!
So here, all events have the class "test".

At the very end I try to display an array of elements which have the class "test". And we see that the table is empty.

Then I will try another way with a "each" by displaying them one by one. And there, nothing is displayed in the console

https://codepen.io/kiuega/pen/oNgMOKJ